# Service Worker Detect Cache Completed

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My PWA has a large data payload. I want to display a 'Please wait...' load page and wait until all caching is complete before launching the full app. Therefore, I need to detect when all caching has completed. The snippet of my service worker is:

```
let appCaches = [{
    name: 'pageload-core-2018-02-14.002',
    urls: [
      './',
      './index.html',
      './manifest.json',
      './sw.js',
      './sw-register.js'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'pageload-icon-2018-02-14.002',
    urls: [
      './icon-32.png',
      './icon-192.png',
      './icon-512.png'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'pageload-data-2019-02-14.002',
    urls: [
      './kjv.js'
    ]
  }
];

let cacheNames = appCaches.map((cache) => cache.name);

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('install');
  event.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function (keys) {
    return Promise.all(appCaches.map(function (appCache) {
      if (keys.indexOf(appCache.name) === -1) {
        caches.open(appCache.name).then(function (cache) {
          return cache.addAll(appCache.urls).then(function () {
            console.log(`Cached: ${appCache.name} @ ${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}`);
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log(`Found: ${appCache.name}`);
        return Promise.resolve(true);
      }
    })).then(function () {
      // Happens first; expected last.
      console.log(`Cache Complete @ ${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}`);
    });
  }));
  self.skipWaiting();
});
```

When I test this with a simulated 3G network, the trace is:

[image]

I do not understand why the 'Cache Complete' message is logged before any of the individual 'Cached' messages are logged; I would expect it to be last. Is there something different about the way Promise.all behaves compared to other promises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oy! What a silly oversight. After breaking the promise chains into individual promises and stepping through the code, the problem became obvious.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('install');
  event.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function (keys) {
    return Promise.all(appCaches.map(function (appCache) {
      if (keys.indexOf(appCache.name) === -1) {
        // Never returned the promise chain to map!!!
        return caches.open(appCache.name).then(function (cache) {
          return cache.addAll(appCache.urls).then(function () {
            console.log(`Cached: ${appCache.name} @ ${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}`);
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log(`Found: ${appCache.name}`);
        return Promise.resolve(true);
      }
    })).then(function () {
      console.log(`Cache Complete @ ${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}`);
    });
  }));
  self.skipWaiting();
});
```

I never returned the promise chain to the `map` function (no explicit `return` always returns `undefined`). So the array passed to `Promise.all` contained only `undefined` values. Therefore, it resolved immediately and hence logged its message before the others.

[image]

Live and learn...

Answer (score 0):

@claytoncarney Do you know how to pass a callback.. or any way to listen to this event from my app?

I try to send a toast message to my user telling them that the data has been cached...

In this case, I send an alert (it's do not work)...

Comment: It is always better to enter your code not post an image of it.  Images can be hard to read for some people.